# How to pick a .xml file on android 11?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-11

I am trying to select a file from an external storage on Android 11. I got read and write permissions, as well as ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission. It doesn't work

```
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```

Help me please =(

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not helpful.  Do you get an error, exception, etc?  What specifically is it doing or not doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, we use File Picker of `Xamarin.Essentials` to pick a single or multiple files from the device.

Install Xamarin.Essentials NuGet package.

Update Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Replace:

```
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```

To:

```
var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(PickOptions.Default);
```

After allowing the permissions, you could pick the file you want.

[image]

For more details about the File Picker, please check the MS document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android